# How to recover an NLTK stem word to a correct word?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, porter-stemmer

After I use the NLTK PorterStemmer to stem a word, the word sometimes becomes an incomplete word, for example, "receive" become "receiv" after stem, which is not a correct word.

So how can I recover an NLTK PorterStemmer stem word to a correct word?

Comment: Unless you've saved the original form before stemming, it's not possible to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of stemming is to reduce a word's inflectional form to a base form, e.g. "receive" to "receiv", "deceive" to "deceiv" or even "different" to "differ".

The stem doesn't need to be exactly the same as the morphological root of the word as long as related words map to the same base form. This is why the NLTK PorterStemmer chops off ends of words, and sometimes those words like "receiv" are not spelled correctly, but this is still expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "You cannot".

Unless it's the only instance of the word, and you have the original text to compare to, it's nigh impossible to recover the word, as a stem of a word could have many variants from which it was reduced.

For example, "receiv" in this case could have been "received" or "receiving" or "receiver" or one of many other variants.

Without exact context, it's impossible to guess which. Sorry.